How to count the no of occurrences of a particular string in a latest log file to read last 5 min data in linux
I want to capture an error code (e.g. 502) from a log file.

The log file is rollover when it's reached to 100 MB like access.log_126427, access.log_197455, etc. There is no specific pattern of the log name.
We want to count the no of occurrences of error code 502 from the latest log file and want the number of occurrences in just the last 5 minutes and not in the entire latest log file.

Anyone kindly help.

PFB log file name.
access_log.1733745600
access_log.1733752774
access_log.1733761132
...


And inside log file data would like
2409:40d1:8a:b2e1:68fe:5cff:fe6d:ec1c, 23.64.1.206, 104.124.54.45 172.27.76.22 - - [12/Dec/2024:20:01:06 +0530] "POST /api/midas/service/beneficiary/v1/banklogo HTTP/1.1" 502 40190 223709
2401:4900:5dea:1400:ec30:5908:d658:7894, 23.64.1.206, 23.45.91.41 172.27.76.22 - - [12/Dec/2024:20:01:06 +0530] "POST /api/midas/service/accounts/v1/accountDetails HTTP/1.1" 200 1082 199338
2401:4900:7c63:b831:fd24:83c5:ad7c:cf90, 104.90.5.244, 104.124.54.45 172.27.76.22 - - [12/Dec/2024:20:01:06 +0530] "GET /minio/etb-topbanners/UPI_Credit_Card_New.png?1734813866141 HTTP/1.1" 502 246932 22834




So you want the number of occurrences in just the last 5 minutes and not the entire latest log file?  If so we need to know what the log file looks like in order to know how the timestamps look.  Also does your 502 error include any other text that could be used to narrow it down?  If you just search for the occurrences of the number 502 you are likely to get false positives.

Please [edit] your question and show us an example of the log file. We can't help you parse data we cannot see. And do you want the last 5 minutes in the file, or the messages from the last 5 minutes? For example, if the last entry of the file is yesterday (so, much more than 5 minutes ago now) do you want no output? Or do you want the last 5 minutes reported in the file, no matter what day it is today?

That sample of log file contains six lines. Surely it should be only three? If you don't give us valid data to parse we're not going to be able to construct code that works in your real situation

This:
perl -MTime::Piece -snle '
    BEGIN{
        my $t = localtime;
        our $now = $t->epoch;
        our $monthsRe = join "|", $t->mon_list;
        our $count = 0;
    }
    m!\[(\d{2}/(?:$monthsRe)/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s.*\sHTTP/\d+\.\d+"?\s+${http_code}\s!;
    my $d = Time::Piece->strptime("$1", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S");
    my $old = $d->strftime("%s");
    my $diff = (($now - $old) + $gap);
    if ($diff > $min and $diff < $max) {$count++}
    END{print $count}
' -- -gap=$({ printf "%s" "0"; date "+%:::z*3600"; } | bc) \
     -min=0 \
     -max=300 \
     -http_code=502 access.log

Some explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75483421/465183

It's require package to run this script. Can you please create a bash script.

I don't know what you mean. You need Perl, the module is a built-in

date "+%:::z*3600" likely outputs +05:30*3600 in the OP's timezone which bc won't like.

This will probably do what you want, using any awk and a version of date that lets you subtract a time interval, e.g. GNU date:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v err=502 -v thresh="$(date -d '-5 mins' +'%F %T')" '
    $(NF-2) == err {
        numErrs[FILENAME]++
        if ( match($0, /\[[^]+]/) ) {
            date = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH+18)
            sub(":","/",date)
            split(date,d,"/")
            mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", d[2]) + 2 ) / 3
            curr = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %s", d[3], mthNr, d[1], d[4])
            if ( curr > thresh ) {
                numRecent[FILENAME]++
                totRecent++
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        printf "latestErrs=%d, prevRecent=%d\n", numErrs[FILENAME], totRecent - numRecent[fname]
    }
' "${@:--}"

but the provided sample input isn't adequate to test it with so it's just an untested guess.
